# Jenkins Error: Powershell Integration with Jenkins

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I mm trying to integrate PowerShell with Jenkins. I am finding it hard to resolve this error as my PowerShell script job is failing as shown below.

```
[own-machine-powershell-job] $ powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy ByPass "& 'C:\Windows\TEMP\hudson3566059468296731803.ps1'"
The system cannot find the file specified
FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "powershell.exe" (in directory "C:\jenkins\workspace\own-machine-powershell-job"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.(Proc.java:244)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.(Proc.java:216)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:816)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:382)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLaunchCallable.call(Launcher.java:1149)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLaunchCallable.call(Launcher.java:1114)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:120)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:62)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at ......remote call to Powershell-Job(Native Method)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1416)
    at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:220)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:781)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:929)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:382)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:97)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:66)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:785)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:205)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:162)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:537)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:408)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.(Proc.java:244)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.(Proc.java:216)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:816)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:382)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLaunchCallable.call(Launcher.java:1149)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLaunchCallable.call(Launcher.java:1114)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:120)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:62)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Build step 'Windows PowerShell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: I have seen other similar posts regarding the same issue, but unable to resolve the issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: I have next to no experience with Jenkins, and no experience at all with Jenkins on Windows, but my first guess would be that it's a PATH issue. `powershell.exe` is located in `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0`. Did you try calling it with its full path?

Comment: You should show how you're trying to execute the script within Jenkins.  A screen grab of the Jenkins build step should help.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to check this locally before trying in jenkins.

If you tried to use the plugin or to execute an external file try to re-check the file path:

The system cannot find the file specified FATAL: command execution failed java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "powershell.exe"

The powershell exe path is wrong.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, in my system environment variables, the powershell.exe path was incorrect. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got it resolved finally.
Basically, in my system environment variables, powershell.exe path was incorrect which I corrected it. Then ran my Jenkins job, but still the same error.
So, I restarted my system, then ran my Jenkins Powershell Job successfully.

Thanks

Comment: This helped me!  Someone whacked the path variable when configuring software on the server for their build

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help anyone else but gonna write it down just for posterity. Make sure your slave is running and connected. I saw this error when my Windows Jenkins slave had been disconnected, but I hadn't set a "restrict where this build can run" so it was running on my master (a Linux machine). Obviously it couldn't find a powershell.exe on there. :D